# Mac OS capture output from shell script that launches application

Tags: bash, console

I have a .Net Core application that I'm running on a Mac.

I am currently using a shell script to launch the executable which is working well however I am wondering where the output from the script is being sent?

Specifically I have the CFBundleExecutable key in the Info.plist file pointing to the script:

```
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>Launch.sh</string>
```

The Launch.sh script in turn runs the .Net Core executable via an exec command like this:

```
bash -c "exec -a \"${Appname}\" nohup ./\"${Appname}\" > \"${Appname}\".Run.log 2>&1 &"
```

Appname is the name of my executable and I do see the output from the app in the ${Appname}.Run.log file but I would like to know if there's a way to capture the output from the calling script Launch.sh?

Comment: How are you launch .Net? What are the contents of your bash file? Shouldn't it just end up on the terminal like any other application (unless you're redirecting the output)?

Comment: post script.  say how you are invoking the script with example.

Comment: why doesn't this work?    myscript  >>name-of-text-file.txt

Comment: in script { bash script statements } >>name-of-text-file.txt

Comment: On superuser, [what-does->>-mean-in-terminal-command](https://superuser.com/questions/1334939/what-does-mean-in-terminal-command/1334975#1334975)

Comment: In the script, you can use the command `exec` to redirect output and/or errors for the rest of the script to a log file. For example, `exec >>/path/to/logfile.log 2>&1` would redirect both standard and error output.

Comment: I hope the edited question sheds some light on what I'm asking for.

Comment: What do you want to do with the output in `Launch.sh`, do you want to process it further? Preventing it from getting written to a log file is easy (just omit the `> \"${Appname}\".Run.log 2>&1` part), but without further steps it will just dump the output into Terminal (if you call `Launch.sh` from there) or have it disappear in thin air (if the application is called from Finder).

Comment: My hope is that when a user launches the app from the Finder and the app does not run properly I'll be able to view the output from Launch.sh and identify what might have gone wrong.